# Laravel nova tool - add datepicker

Tags: laravel, datepicker, vuejs2, laravel-nova

I create a nova tool and need to have a datepicker.

In order to see the Nova datepicker, I did the following:
I added to User migration file:

```
$table->date('birthday')->nullable();
```

And reflected it in `User.php` and `Nova\User.php`:

```
public static $search = [
    'id', 'name', 'email', 'birthday'
];

public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
           :
           :
        Date::make('birthday')
            ->sortable(),

    ];
}
```

I got a nice datepicker:
 [image]

Now I would like to have the same in my tool, but cannot manage to attach it to the date field.

By-the-way, the date field in user form has the following html:

```
<input data-v-d0bd8056="" dusk="birthday" name="birthday"
       type="text" placeholder="2018-10-25" 
       class="w-full form-control form-input form-input-bordered flatpickr-input active">
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it!

I found the [flatpicker component page](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component) and followed the installation and usage instructions.

Then in order to have it nicely formed:

```
<flat-pickr v-model="fromDate" class="form-control form-input form-input-bordered datepicker-field"></flat-pickr>
```

And in `<style>` tag I added:

```
.datepicker-field {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Clean and easy!